# Perl use to loop on columns and rows

Tags: perl

I have a file of following type

```
,A,B,C,D,
M,X,-,-,X,
N,X,-,-,-,
```

I need to convert this data using perl to following output; by replacing the place wherever "X" is present with the data available in respective column of first row.

```
M,A,D,
N,A,
```

I have thought to save the first row as an array and then count the place where "X" comes in second and following rows and replace it with the item in the array at that position.

Please let me know a way to do this, it will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Stack overflow isn't really a 'do my work for me' service, but rather about helping you solve your programming problems. Can I suggest this question would be improved by actually trying to solve it, and then pointing out where you got stuck?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i would improve on this and sure will post with actual problems. I didn't know the use of this portal as i recently joined. Will keep it in mind in future.

Comment: [ask] is a useful thing to review.

Answer (score 2):

People seem determined to make their solutions as hard to understand as possible, So here's something a little less opaque.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

# Array of the replacement letters
my @replace = split /,/, <>;
# Remove the newline from array elements
chomp @replace;

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  # array of data
  my @data = split /,/;

  # replacements
  for my $i (0 .. $#data) {
    if ($data[$i] eq 'X') {
      $data[$i] = $replace[$i];
    }
  }

  # remove empty elements
  @data = grep { $_ ne '-' } @data;

  say join ',', @data;
}
```

Run it by passing your input file on the command line. So something like:

```
$ ./letters letters.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input.txt 
,A,B,C,D,
M,X,-,-,X,
N,X,-,-,-,
$ perl -F, -alE'$,=",";$i=-1;$.==1&&(@D=@F)||say map{$i++;$_ eq X?$D[$i]:$_ eq"-"?():$_}@F' input.txt
M,A,D
N,A
```

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -F, -anle '
    if($.==1){
        @S=@F;
        next;
    }
    @A=();
    for(1..$#F){
        push @A, $S[$_] if $F[$_] eq "X"
    }
    print join ",", $F[0], @A
' < input
```

From `perl -h`

```
-F/pattern/       split() pattern for -a switch (//'s are optional)
-a                autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into @F)
-n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
-l[octal]         enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
```

Then

```
@S is used to save @F when reading first line ($.==1)
@A is used to push values
```

Comment: This could really use some explanation.

Comment: Please help me understand the code, as i am a newbee to perl.